# How to rearrange the small rectangular into a big rectangular in bin packing algorithmn

Tags: python, matplotlib, drawing, bin-packing

I'm new to python and I am trying to make re-arrange the rectangle from raw data. I'm using bin packing algorithmn and I want to sort it with color like below. Please need help?

Output Now:

[image]

Expected Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are small changes in the code please follow below code once:

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
    fig = plt.figure() 
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111) 

    temp_y=0
    i=0
    layout_height = 300
    layout_width = 300

    ax.set_xlim([0, layout_height])
    ax.set_ylim([0, layout_width])

    area_height = [80, 75, 50, 60, 52, 72, 100, 120, 150]
    area_width = [50, 46, 52, 52, 50, 48, 25, 40, 48]

    for (i,j) in zip(area_height, area_width):
       print(i,j)
       ax.add_patch(Rectangle((0, temp_y), float(j), float(i),edgecolor ='black',facecolor = 'red'))
       temp_y = temp_y + float(i)
```

Comment: thanks. What I want is to fill up the empty space as much as possible

Comment: @AshWinchester are you trying to fill the empty space with some other color in the plot?

Comment: I want to fill up the respective rectangle from the list area_height and area_width, there are no relation in between the color. I updated the expected output again. Hopefully, It will be clear for you